# Ehcache web CacheManager.replaceCacheWithDecoratedCache throws NPE

Tags: java, configuration, ehcache

I have a very basic setup: Struts2 web-app, added to it Ehcache-Web and trying to make it work.

Here's my `ehcache.xml`:

```
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ehcache.org/ehcache.xsd"
         updateCheck="false"
         dynamicConfig="false"
         >
    <diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir"/>

    <defaultCache
       maxElementsInMemory="100"
       maxElementsOnDisk="1000" 
       eternal="false"
       overflowToDisk="true"
       diskPersistent="false"
       memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"
       timeToIdleSeconds="120000"
       timeToLiveSeconds="120000"
       />

    <cache name="searchDspCache"
       maxElementsInMemory="100"
       maxElementsOnDisk="1000" 
       eternal="false"
       overflowToDisk="true"
       diskPersistent="false"
       memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"
       timeToIdleSeconds="120000"
       timeToLiveSeconds="120000"    
    />   

</ehcache>
```

Here's how I configured the Ehcache web filter

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>searchDspCachingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>net.sf.ehcache.constructs.web.filter.SimplePageCachingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>suppressStackTrace</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cacheName</param-name>
            <param-value>searchDspCache</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
```

When the app is deployed in either Jetty or Glassfish, I get this error right upfront:

```
20111118T115824,294 [sales-web]  FATAL [Timer-1] (net.sf.ehcache.constructs.web.filter.Filter:201) - Could not initialise servlet filter.
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.replaceCacheWithDecoratedCache(CacheManager.java:950)
    at net.sf.ehcache.constructs.web.filter.CachingFilter.doInit(CachingFilter.java:92)
```

Followed these instructions from Ehcache website:

http://ehcache.org/documentation/modules/web-caching

Manually downloaded the correct eccache-web and ehcache-core sources from their repo:

https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/sourceforge/net/sf/ehcache/

And checked the lines of code reported in the log:

`net.sf.ehcache.constructs.web.filter.CachingFilter.doInit(CachingFilter.java:92)` is:

```
/**
 * The cache name can be set through init parameters. If it is set it is
 * stored here.
 */ <---- this is line 92
protected String cacheName;
```

`at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.replaceCacheWithDecoratedCache(CacheManager.java:950)` is:

```
// NPE guard
if (cacheName == null || cacheName.length() == 0) {
    return;
} <-- this is line 950
```

I know I'm severely missing something but I don't know what. Can someone who's already done this tell me what I'm doing wrong, or what I'm missing. I just wanna do some simple caching of my HTML content. Thankx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, well, to my personal embarrassment I've solved it. Here's the short answer:

My project also uses Hibernate. Hibernate comes with an old version of Ehcache. In my Maven setup what happened was that the old version of Ehcache (version 1.2.3), the one that comes with Hibernate was taking priority over the one I was adding myself (ehcache-web v 2.0.4 & ehcache-core 2.4.6). And since the old, Hibernate, version of Ehcache didn't support naming your cache in the `SimplePageCachingFilter`, I had the error.

The long answer:

To solve it, I've excluded the Ehcache dependency from my Hibernate dependency in the pom.xml of the project like so:

```
<dependency>
          <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
          <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
          <version>3.4.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
          <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
          <version>3.2.7.ga</version>
          <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
                <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
          </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

What I did to discover this issue is use the Maven dependency tree command like so:

```
C:\_andrei\me\myprojects2\dynamicFormGwtSpringWicket\springMvcApp>mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=net.sf.ehcache
(...)
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:tree (default-cli) @ springMcvApp ---
[INFO] g1:springMcvApp:war:2.0
[INFO] +- g1:modelApp:jar:2.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.hibernate:hibernate:jar:3.2.7.ga:compile
[INFO] |     \- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] \- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache-web:jar:2.0.4:compile
[INFO]    \- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache-core:jar:2.4.6:compile
```

This shows me that the `net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:jar:1.2.3` dependency which comes from Hibernate, which in turn comes from `g1:modelApp:jar:2.0:compile` has priority. After adding the exlude as shown below, redoing the dependency tree command shows me just:

```
C:\_andrei\me\myprojects2\dynamicFormGwtSpringWicket\springMvcApp>mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=net.sf.ehcache
(...)
INFO] g1:springMcvApp:war:2.0
INFO] \- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache-web:jar:2.0.4:compile
INFO]    \- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache-core:jar:2.4.6:compile
```

And in fact with this setup, I can start my app with `SimplePageCachingFilter` configured as described in my question and everything starts ok, no more exceptions. The Ehcache log also shows that the filter is actually working and doing stuff.

I'd really like to thank @jeha for helping me with this and putting me on the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

> `} <-- this is line 950`

I don't think this is the problematic line of code - did you look at right sources? From a quick look, [CacheManager.replaceCacheWithDecoratedCache of Ehcache version 1.5](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.sf.ehcache/ehcache/1.5.0/net/sf/ehcache/CacheManager.java#CacheManager.replaceCacheWithDecoratedCache%28net.sf.ehcache.Ehcache,net.sf.ehcache.Ehcache%29), is a more promising:

```
if (!ehcache.equals(decoratedCache)) { // line 950
```

which would mean, to explain the NPE, that `ehcache` is `null`.

Name your cache `SimplePageCachingFilter` in your `ehcache.xml`:

```
<cache name="SimplePageCachingFilter" ... />
```

and it will work. The reason for that is [`SimplePageCachingFilter`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.sf.ehcache/ehcache/1.5.0/net/sf/ehcache/constructs/web/filter/SimplePageCachingFilter.java) must have a cache named `SimplePageCachingFilter`! You can leave out the `init-param` for `cacheName` from `web.xml` for the same reason.

Comment: I'll try this, seems promising, you're on the right track with the correct source code. Tho about the cache name I don't know... that doc on their own web-site clearly shows that your filter accepts a cacheName parameter, and you can put in whatever value you want, just as long as you make sure that you use that same value to name a cache in your ehcache.xml... I'll try it on sunday and tell you what happend. Thanx!

Comment: @AndreiBodnarescu: The code clearly shows that `SimplePageCachingFilter.getCacheName()` always returns `"SimplePageCachingFilter"` ;-)

Comment: Yes sir, it does, you're right. And it's a bad on my side that I didn't whack at the issue some more in order to find the correct code. But in the other hand, on their website here: http://ehcache.org/documentation/modules/web-caching, if you scroll to about half the article, you'll see an example of a SimplePageCachingFilter configured with a cache named "CachePage1CachingFilter".

Comment: @AndreiBodnarescu: yes, I have seen this example - anyway, I haven't tried, but on the other hand I don't need to ... the code (for the 1.5. version) tells a different story ... I'd be more than surprised if this example would work exactly like that ...

Comment: Well, the simple answer is this: I'm not crazy but I'm stupid. You CAN infact configure the SimplePageCachingFilter with a cache with whatever name, as long as you declare it in the filter's config (via the cacheName param). So the example on their page is correct. My problem was that I was using Hibernate as well, and Hibernate already comes with an old version of Ehcache, and THAT old version did not support naming your cache in that filter (in that old version you had to use a cache named "SimplePageCachingFilter"). So simply excluding that Ehcache from the Hibernate dependency solved it

Comment: @AndreiBodnarescu: Thanks for clearing up the dependency issue.